# Ajax Request Not Working on Phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, phonegap

I should really post this question since I just can't find working solution for ajax request with phonegap.

I'm using the latest phonegap and android studio. 
When I previewed in in AVD, everything is fine except the ajax call.

I've also added a whitelist plugin for cordova (actually), in phonegap I've run this command:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Anda Here is my config.xml file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.halalprowebdesign.universityassistance" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <name>University Assistance</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

More over, I've make sure that the script was working properly when testing on phonegap desktop app server.

If anyone have an idea about this, 
I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what errors are you seeing?

Comment: That is the strange part. No error that can be used as a clue.
Here it is:

`08-10 06:13:26.964 2975-3169/com.halalprowebdesign.universityassistance E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/css/images/ajax-loader.gif

08-10 06:13:39.012 1747-1747/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.`

Comment: also:
`08-10 06:13:24.813 1178-1565/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)`

Comment: ohh, okay. another error from android device monitor:
`08-10 06:38:50.582: W/SystemWebViewClient(3245): URL blocked by whitelist: http://localhost/university-assistance/index.php?route=android/app/login`

Comment: Now I know what exactly going on. 
The things is, ajax call in localhost just doesn't work. 
I don't know why. After moved the web app to the hosting provider. 

But, I'm still corious why localhost ajax request denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace localhost with the server address. You can't point it at localhost while it is hosted on your (internet) server.